# Elasticsearch put response hits to new list

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

When I try put response from elasticsearch to new list with new object name , result is not correctly. When I add hit to list result is correct what`s going on ? How I should fix it? Any ideas what I should to do?

Not correct means total result is different and not correct.

That`s is not correct response:

```
public Map findAllByIndexParams(TransIndexSearchParams searchParams) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getBuyer()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("buyer", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_type()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("comment_type", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getItem()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("item", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSeller()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("seller", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTree_cat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tree_cat", v))));

        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many sellers
        if (searchParams.getSellers() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSellers().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("seller", v)));
            });
        }

        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCats() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCats().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_text()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getComment_text()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("comment_text"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("ts").from(searchParams.getTsFrom()).to(searchParams.getTsTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);
        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        List<TransIndex> rowsTrans = new ArrayList();
        List rows = new ArrayList();
        Map response = new HashMap();
        String scrollId = searchTemplate.scan(searchQuery.build(), 1000, false);

        Page<TransIndex> page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, TransIndex.class);

        if (page.hasContent()) {

            while (true) {

                for (TransIndex hit : page.getContent()) {
                    Map row = new HashMap();
                    row.put("endts", auctionRepository.findTransactionAuctionById(hit.getItem(), hit.getTransactionIndexId()).get("endts"));
                    row.put("startts", auctionRepository.findTransactionAuctionById(hit.getItem(), hit.getTransactionIndexId()).get("startts"));
                    row.put("qty", auctionRepository.findTransactionAuctionById(hit.getItem(), hit.getTransactionIndexId()).get("qty"));
                    row.put("price", auctionRepository.findTransactionAuctionById(hit.getItem(), hit.getTransactionIndexId()).get("price"));
                    row.put("buyer", hit.getBuyer());
                    row.put("cat", hit.getCat());
                    row.put("comment_text", hit.getComment_text());
                    row.put("comment_type", hit.getComment_type());
                    row.put("item", hit.getItem());
                    row.put("seller", hit.getSeller());
                    row.put("title", hit.getTitle());
                    row.put("transactionIndexId", hit.getTransactionIndexId());
                    row.put("tree_cat", hit.getTree_cat());
                    row.put("ts", hit.getTs());
                    rows.add(row);
                }
                page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, TransIndex.class);
                if (page.hasContent() == false) {
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        response.put("content", rows);
        return response;
    }
```

That is correct:

```
public Map findAllByIndexParams(TransIndexSearchParams searchParams) {
        final List<FilterBuilder> filters = Lists.newArrayList();
        final NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(matchAllQuery());

        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getBuyer()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("buyer", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("cat", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_type()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("comment_type", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getItem()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("item", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSeller()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("seller", v))));
        Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTree_cat()).ifPresent(v -> filters.add(boolFilter().must(termFilter("tree_cat", v))));

        final BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();

        //access for many sellers
        if (searchParams.getSellers() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getSellers().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("seller", v)));
            });
        }

        //access for many categories
        if (searchParams.getCats() != null) {
            Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getCats().split(",")).ifPresent(v -> {
                filters.add(boolFilter().must(termsFilter("cat", v)));
            });
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTitle()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getTitle()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("title"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getComment_text()).isPresent()) {
            boolQueryBuilder.should(queryStringQuery(searchParams.getComment_text()).analyzeWildcard(true).field("comment_text"));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getPriceTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("price").from(searchParams.getPriceFrom()).to(searchParams.getPriceTo()));
        }

        if (Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsFrom()).isPresent()
                || Optional.ofNullable(searchParams.getTsTo()).isPresent()) {
            filters.add(rangeFilter("ts").from(searchParams.getTsFrom()).to(searchParams.getTsTo()));
        }

        searchQuery.withQuery(boolQueryBuilder);
        FilterBuilder[] filterArr = new FilterBuilder[filters.size()];
        filterArr = filters.toArray(filterArr);
        searchQuery.withFilter(andFilter(filterArr));

        List<TransIndex> rowsTrans = new ArrayList();
        List rows = new ArrayList();
        Map response = new HashMap();
        String scrollId = searchTemplate.scan(searchQuery.build(), 1000, false);

        Page<TransIndex> page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, TransIndex.class);

        if (page.hasContent()) {

            while (true) {

                for (TransIndex hit : page.getContent()) {
                    rows.add(hit);
                }
                page = searchTemplate.scroll(scrollId, 5000L, TransIndex.class);
                if (page.hasContent() == false) {
                    break;
                }

            }

        }
        response.put("content", rows);
        return response;
    }
```

And the next question is how I can speed up searching? When I`v got many records its have been searching so long time example 500 records finds > 30 seconds.